# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start no funciona en IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cuando ejecuto System.Diagnostics.Process.Start desde mi aplicacion ASP.Net de forma local(desde visual studio) funciona, pero cuando la ejecuto desde localhost en iis deja de funcinar.

alguien sabe porque y como puedo hacer para funcione en IIS

Comment: porque querrias hacer un process.start desde IIS???? obviamente localmente funciona porque tenes permisos.

Comment: quiero abrir un documento de excel pero sin descargarlo, es decir que al dar clic me ejecute el programa de excel.

Comment: Pero ese programa se va a ejecutar en el servidor, no en la pc del usuario.. o sea, cada persona que haga click en ese link va a abrir un archivo en el servidor (mas alla del problema de permisos que tenes). Para que querrias hacer algo asi?

Comment: es un proyecto que estoy haciendo